# How can I feature test for a valid duration using Laravel's validation helpers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to write a Feature test that checks that the provided `end_time` does not occur before the provided `start_time`. I've spent the last few days; I think I've seen about every SO post and still having trouble getting it through my head.

I have been able to successfully test/validate based on a condition:

**MyTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function a_blackout_that_does_not_close_the_location_requires_an_end_time()
{
    $table = 'my_table';

    $blackout = factory(Blackout::class)->create([
        'closed' => 0,
    ]);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas($table, [
        'end_time' => $blackout->end_time,
    ]);
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        ...
        'date' => ['required'],
        'closed' => ['nullable'],
        'start_time' => ['required_if:closed,0'],  // works great
        'end_time' => ['required_if:closed,0'],    // works great
    ]);

    $blackout = new Blackout($attributes);

    ...
}
```

Now I want to make sure that any provided `end_time` is not before a provided `start_time`.

**MyTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function a_blackout_end_time_cannot_be_before_the_start_time()
{
    $blackout = factory(Blackout::class)->raw([
        'closed' => 0,
        'start_time' => '08:00:00',
        'end_time' => '07:00:00',
    ]);

    $response = $this->post('api/v1/blackouts', $blackout)
        ->assertSessionHasErrors('end_time');
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

**MyController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        ...
        'date' => ['required'],
        'closed' => ['nullable'],
        'start_time' => ['required_if:closed,0'],
        'end_time' => ['required_if:closed,0|after:start_time'],
    ]);

    $blackout = new Blackout($attributes);

    ...
}
```

I keep getting an error in my test:

> 1) Tests\Feature\BlackoutsTest::a_blackout_end_time_cannot_be_before_the_start_time
>   Session is missing expected key [errors].
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

That suggests that it isn't getting the correct error(s) set/returned from the validation. I've tried a bunch of ways to format the `start_time` and `end_time` to try to compare.

Further in my controller, I'm able to compare the times relatively easily:

**MyController.php**

```
...
$start_time = strtotime($blackout->start_time);
$end_time = strtotime($blackout->end_time);

if ($end_time <= $start_time) {
    // Invalid duration
} else {
    $blackout->save();
}

...
```

I am struggling how to validate through the validator so I can leverage the error message(s) better.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Thank you @Thomas Van der Veen. Clearly, I'm learning so while looking through the json examples I believe I'm doing a number of things wrong (big surprise).

I've updated my test to now use `postJson` instead of `post`. I'm checking for a `422` response and that there should be an `end_time` error.

```
/** @test */
public function a_blackout_end_time_cannot_be_before_the_start_time()
{
    $blackout = factory(Blackout::class)->raw([
        'closed' => 0,
        'start_time' => '08:00:00',
        'end_time' => '07:00:00',
     ]);

     $response = $this->postJson('api/v1/blackouts', $blackout)
         ->assertStatus(422)
         ->assertJsonValidationErrors('end_time');
 }
```

**MyController.php**

```
$attributes = $request->validate([
   ...
   'date' => ['required'],
   'closed' => ['nullable'],
   'start_time' => ['required_if:closed,0|date|'],
   'end_time' => ['required_if:closed,0|date|after:start_time'],
]);

...

$blackout->save();

return response()->json(['data' => $blackout], 201);
```

The test response is:

> 1) Tests\Feature\BlackoutsTest::a_blackout_end_time_cannot_be_before_the_start_time
>   Expected status code 422 but received 201.
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

Which tells me my validation is bad since it's getting through to a 201.

Thank you both for your help. I feel like I'm starting to talk myself in circles & I'm making this way harder than it is.

Comment: It has to do with the kind of assertion you are doing, `assertSessionHasErrors`. No session is present since you request an API. Take a took at [`assertJsonValidationErrors`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#assert-json-validation-errors) or one of the other json assertions.

Comment: Well, I want to make sure that `end_time` is *after* `start_time`. In my test I'm forcing an entry where the `end_time` is *before* the `start_time`. I am hoping to get/verify that my validation is working. I'm expecting to see some sort of `end_time` error for the test to pass. Perhaps I'm doing it all wrong...

Comment: Ha! I have no doubt I'm doing a number of things incorrectly. I appreciate all suggestions. :) I did try and no luck. I've edited my answer to follow @Thomas Van der Veen's suggestion.

Comment: The request is working now. You could now check if the request data is at all correct by outputting it with `dd($request->all())`. The `after` rule (like the [`before`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-before) rule) is using `strtotime` during its comparison. Maybe check this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your suggestions! They both helped get me to this answer. Although I believe I am still [writing/executing tests incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154369/why-is-my-validation-rule-not-working-in-my-laravel-controller?noredirect=1#comment106395175_60154369)

Here is the solution I ended up with, If there is a better way please let me know so I can update my answer.

I ended up writing a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) and passing in my `time_start` to compare the two times.

**MyTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function a_blackout_end_time_cannot_be_before_the_start_time()
{
    $blackout = factory(Blackout::class)->raw([
        'closed' => 0,
        'time_start' => '08:00',
        'time_end' => '07:00',
    ]);

    $response = $this->postJson('api/v1/blackouts', $blackout)
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors('time_end');
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        ...
        'date' => ['required', new DateFormatRule], // Custom rule
        'closed' => 'nullable',
        'time_start' => 'required_if:closed,0',
        'time_end' => ['required_if:closed,0', new TimeDurationRule($request->time_start)],
    ]);

    $blackout = new Blackout($attributes);
    ...
}
```

**TimeDurationRule.php**

```
**
 * Create a new rule instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($time_start)
{
    $this->time_start = $time_start;
}

/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return strtotime($value) > strtotime($this->time_start);
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'Time duration is invalid.';
}
```

In my test I am getting a 422 response as expected. I can verify things are working by changing the name of the expected error from `time_end` to `time_end123` and I'll get an error -- saying It was expecting `time_end` not `time_end123.