# Why is my validation rule not working in my Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to write a test that checks that a date is formatted correctly. Looking at the docs it seems pretty straight-forward.

Here is my test. I am submitting an invalid date format to my controller:

**MyTest.php**

```
 /** @test */
public function a_date_must_be_formatted_correctly()
{
    $foo = factory(Foo::class)->raw([
        'date' => date('d/m/Y'),
    ]);

    $response = $this->postJson('api/v1/foo', $foo)
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors('date');
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
    ]);
    ...
}
```

I get a passing test each time.

I have also tried wrapping the format in quotes: `'date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',`

I'm expecting to get a `422` back saying my `date` is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `Foo::class`?

Comment: It's my example model (In my case it's a `Blackout`). It has a fillable attribute of `date` that I'm trying to make sure the correct format is passed in.

Comment: What does `json_serialize($foo)` look like? Usually you'd send an array of data to test inputs and not the actual model itself

Comment: That's likely the issue. I'm learning about TDD so my apologies. I'll try and update my answer if needed. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up writing a custom rule. I don't think this is the correct solution though given that Laravel has the handy built-in stuff. I feel like I should be leveraging that instead. In my case I am working with Blackout date(s).

Hers is what I ended up with. If there is a way to make the built-in methods work, please let me know so I can update the answer.

**MyTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function a_blackout_date_must_be_formatted_correctly()
{
    $blackout = factory(Blackout::class)->raw([
        'date' => date('d/m/Y'),
    ]);

    $response = $this->postJson('api/v1/blackouts', $blackout)
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors('date');
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        'date' => ['required', new DateFormatRule],
        ...
    ]);

    $blackout = new Blackout($attributes);

    ...

}
```

**DateFormatRule.php**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    // The format we're looking for.
    $format = 'Y-m-d';

    // Create a new DateTime object.
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $value);

    // Verify that the date provided is formatted correctly.
    return $date && $date->format($format) === $value;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'Invalid date format.';
}
```

In my test I am getting a `422` response as expected. I can verify things are working by changing the name of the expected error from `date` to `date123` and I'll get an error -- saying It was expecting `date` not `date123`.

Hope this helps someone!